# Kafka: No message seen on console consumer after message sent by Java Producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka. I created a java producer on my local machine and setup a Kafka broker on another machine, say M2, on the network(I can ping,SSH, connect to this machine). On the Producer side in the Eclipse console I get "Message sent". But when I check the console consumer on machine M2 I cannot see those messages.

My java producer code is:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class KafkaMessageProducer  {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        KafkaMessageProducer reportObj = new KafkaMessageProducer();
        reportObj.send();

    }

    public void send(){

        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "135.113.133.60:9092");
        config.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        config.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(config);
        int maxMessages = 5;
        int count = 0;
        while(count < maxMessages){
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test", "msg", "message --- #"+count++));
            System.out.println("Message send.."+count);
        }
        producer.close();
    }

}
```

Can you please let me know where I'm going wrong? I can send messages locally on machine M2 from the console producer.
Note: Even when I change the IP address to the full hostname of the Kafka Broker it still has the same issue.

Update: I also think that the Producer is able to connect to the Kafka broker and send the messages, but the Kafka Broker does not pass these messages to the consumer. If I change the IP address or the port to Zookeeper(which is running on the same node as the Kafka Broker), and see Zookeeper's log, it gets the Producer ping and then rejects the session.

Update2: I created a Producer jar and ran this jar on Machine M2 and it worked. So it seems that there is something wrong with the way Producer tries to connect to the Kafka broker. Not sure yet what is the problem.

Comment: Did  you have the console consumer up and running before the producer send the message?  Have you tried to read from the beginning of the topic?

Comment: Yes. The console consumer was up and running. I also tried it after producer sent the msgs. I am reading form console consumer from the beginning of the topic.

Comment: Unrelated: I found that other question not worth so many downvotes. So I am giving some compensation here ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer and I'm posting here in case anyone else has the same issue. Use the Kafka broker setting advertised.hostname when you are trying to connect remotely. This worked for me.

Comment: please elaborate a bit more, can you please provide the whole config line which you have added/changed. (the way you have described the question, please describe your answer too). Waiting for your response and thanks in advance.

Comment: @DynamicRemo  In the <DIR-PATH>\Kafka\config\server.properties you need to add this: `port=9092  advertised.host.name=localhost` Notice that localhost is used because I'm not using any remote m/c.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an idea for debugging - try `producer.send(/* record */).get();`
That is, wait for the result from the `Future` returned from the `send()` method. Could be that there's an exception on producer side and it's simply ignored in the background.

Comment: After doing that it remains stuck. The only thing printed on the console is the warning: 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use code as follows to read the metadata info for the kafka topic to see if the broker received the messages. That can help debugging.

```
SimpleConsumer consumer = new SimpleConsumer(broker.host(), broker.port(), 100000,
      64 * 1024, "your_group_id");
List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
topics.add(topic);
TopicMetadataRequest req = new TopicMetadataRequest(topics);

TopicMetadataResponse resp = simpleConsumer.send(req);
if (resp.topicsMetadata().size() != 1) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Expected one metadata for topic "
      + topic + " found " + resp.topicsMetadata().size());
}

TopicMetadata topicMetaData = resp.topicsMetadata().get(0);
```

Comment: Where do I run this? On my local machine or machine M2?

Comment: you can run this from any host that can talk to the kafka broker.

Comment: One more question- Where do I mention the Machine M2's details above, if I run this on my local machine??